# NPE when partially updating Elasticsearch Index

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm following the example over [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html) for updating a set of tags using the partial update in Elasticsearch.

Following is my script:

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.deviceTags.add(params.tags)",
    "params": {
      "tags": "search"
    }
  }
}
```

Request URL is:

```
https://aws-es-service-url/devices/device/123/_update
```

But I'm getting the following response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "remote_transport_exception",
                "reason": "[fBaExM8][x.x.x.x:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "failed to execute script",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "runtime error",
            "script_stack": [
                "ctx._source.deviceTags.add(params.tags)",
                "                                 ^---- HERE"
            ],
            "script": "ctx._source.deviceTags.add(params.tags)",
            "lang": "painless",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "null_pointer_exception",
                "reason": null
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Any idea of what I have done wrong?

Comment: Which version of ES do you have?

Comment: version is ES 5.3

Comment: Can you try to remove `params.` and only keep `tags`?

Comment: then I'm getting:  "caused_by": {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Variable [tags] is not defined."
            }

Comment: Are you 100% certain that your document with id 123 has a non-null field called `deviceTags`?

Comment: device tags param is initially null but the error points to `params.` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162391/discussion-between-maddy-and-val).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `deviceTags` array is initially null, you have two ways to solve this

A. Use `upsert` to make sure that `deviceTags` gets added to your document initially

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "ctx._source.deviceTags.add(params.tags)",
    "params": {
      "tags": "search"
    }
  },
  "upsert": {
    "deviceTags": ["search"]
  }
}
```

B. Protect your code against NPE

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "inline": "(ctx._source.deviceTags = ctx._source.deviceTags ?: []).add(params.tags)",
    "params": {
      "tags": "search"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! there should be a small change: `"inline": "(ctx._source.deviceTags = ctx._source.deviceTags ?: []).add(params.tags)"`